# how to display the selected element (Json) with event.currentTarget Javascript only

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, events

I'm trying to retrieve and display the element clicked from javascript but I only succeeded by displaying with innerText or innerHtml but that's not what I want!
It would simply be necessary to display the div with all the information of the element clicked, it is the information in a Json file to recover in the html with php!
Thanks for your help, I know this is a trifle but for the moment I'm lost, I just have to open the div on the element clicked with the information on it! Here is all the code (phtml and javascript for your help) . Thank you

```
<article>
   <!--Notre Carte-->
   <img src="image/carte_meteo.png" alt="Carte météo Ile de la réunion" />
   <!--Nos éléments JSON pour enrichir notre carte-->

   <?php foreach ($decode_json->meteo->bulletin->ville as $key) : ?>

   <div class="button-read-more" id="<?= $key->{'-id'}; ?>">
      <!--Image d'illustration-->
      <img id="<?= $key->{'-id'}; ?>" class="max_img_soleil" src="image/soleil.png" alt="Illustration météo soleil" />
      <input type="hidden" id="v_a" value="<?= $key->{'-id'}; ?>">
      <div id="infos_plus" class="none_meteo">                           
         <p><strong><?= $key->{'-id'}; ?></strong></p>
         <p><?= $key->{'-temperature_mini'}; ?>°</p>
         <p><?= $key->{'-temperature_maxi'}; ?>°</p>
         <p>Temps : <?= $key->{'-temps'}; ?></p>
         <p>Direction vent : <?= $key->{'-vent_direction'}; ?></p>
         <p>Force vent : <?= $key->{'-vent_force'}; ?></p>
         <p>Vent rafales : <?= $key->{'-vent_rafales'}; ?></p>
         <p>Hummidité : <?= $key->{'-humidite'}; ?></p>
       </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</article>
```

function open(event) {

```
//Récupération de notre élément en question
//Affichage de notre élément en question

document.querySelector("#infos_plus").innerHTML = event.currentTarget.textContent;  

document.querySelector("#infos_plus").classList.toggle('display_meteo');

document.querySelector("#infos_plus").classList.remove('none_meteo');
```

}

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
     /**
     * Notre détail météo sur carte
     */
    buttonReadMore = document.querySelectorAll(".button-read-more");       
    //On boucle notre tableau
     buttonReadMore.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
         //console.log(btn);
      //Appel de nos fonctions avec en paramétre notre événement (pour l'ouverture)
          open(event)          
      });
      //Fermeture
      btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", none);
      });
 });
```

Comment: try  event.currentTarget.outerHTML

Comment: [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is not for "opening" divs ... You're overriding a native method.